# Lenovo K8 Note + Oreo: can't receive android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions

I'm a developer of a small app on Google Play. It uses PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS permission to track outgoing calls. Everything worked well on Lenovo K8 Note with Android 7.1, but after upgrading to Oreo my broadcast receiver does not receive ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL intent.

Due to logs no faults, just like the permission wasn't mentioned in the manifest file. ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED is being tracked well with the same broadcast receiver. And yes, the app asks for pairs of permissions Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE + Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS at runtime, target SDK is 27.

Does anyone have a clue about that?

Thanks in advance.

UPD: The app runs well on many others devices with Oreo without issues.

Comment: can you go to settings and check if `PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` has been granted?

Comment: @Sagar yes, it's granted. Also tried to turn off/turn on that permission, no effect.